# xlsx file created with groovy cannot be open because the format or extension is not valid

Tags: groovy

im trying to create xlsx file with groovy.
i have Soapui open source 5.6.0
i have microsoft office 365
Running with windows 10

i added these jars is lib/ext:

```
commons-compress-1.20.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
poi-5.0.0.jar
poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar
```

With this line: Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
i can create xls file for excel version 97-2003

With this line: Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
i can create xlsx file but cannot open.

What is the probleme here, i downloaded the latest jars for POI.
Do i missing something here?

Thank you for your help.

My code is:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;

import java.io.*; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook; 

  
public class CreateSheet { 
    public static void main(String[] args)  
      throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    { 
  
        // Creating xls file
        //Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); 

         // Creating xlsx file
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  
        // An output stream accepts output bytes and sends them to sink. 
        OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx"); 
          
        // Creating Sheets using sheet object 
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Test");         
        wb.write(fileOut); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be you're not closing the stream

try:

```
class CreateSheet { 

    static main(args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
  
         // Creating xlsx file
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()

        // Creating Sheets using sheet object 
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Test")

        new File("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx").withOutputStream { fileOut ->
            wb.write(fileOut)
        }          
    } 
}
```

Comment: i tried but now it says: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable

Comment: You're probably missing a dependency

Comment: Maybe but there is no error and i cant see any trace error.

Comment: There is a bug with POI, it works with other version.